# gcc make error libcpp/charset.c(1747): error: identifier "saved_error_handler" is undefined

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, configure

Hi I'm trying to install gcc-8.1.0 on a cluster (SHARCNET, linux system). 
Here is my configure and make:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/zhuobuer/gcc-8.1.0/8.1.0/ --enable-multilib
make
```

It returns to me with the error shown as below:

```
checking for iconv... (cached) no
../.././libcpp/system.h(198): warning #47: incompatible redefinition of macro "__NO_STRING_INLINES"
  #define __NO_STRING_INLINES
          ^

configure: creating ./config.status
../.././libcpp/charset.c(1747): error: identifier "saved_error_handler" is undefined
    bool (*saved_error_handler) (cpp_reader *, int, int, rich_location *,
           ^

../.././libcpp/charset.c(1747): error: type name is not allowed
    bool (*saved_error_handler) (cpp_reader *, int, int, rich_location *,
                                 ^

../.././libcpp/charset.c(1747): error: expected an expression
    bool (*saved_error_handler) (cpp_reader *, int, int, rich_location *,
                                             ^

../.././libcpp/charset.c(1747): error: type name is not allowed
    bool (*saved_error_handler) (cpp_reader *, int, int, rich_location *,
                                               ^

../.././libcpp/charset.c(1747): error: type name is not allowed
    bool (*saved_error_handler) (cpp_reader *, int, int, rich_location *,
                                                    ^

../.././libcpp/charset.c(1747): error: type name is not allowed
    bool (*saved_error_handler) (cpp_reader *, int, int, rich_location *,
                                                         ^

../.././libcpp/charset.c(1747): error: expected an expression
    bool (*saved_error_handler) (cpp_reader *, int, int, rich_location *,
                                                                        ^

../.././libcpp/charset.c(1748): error: expected an expression
                   const char *, va_list *)
                   ^

../.././libcpp/charset.c(1748): error: type name is not allowed
                   const char *, va_list *)
                                 ^

../.././libcpp/charset.c(1748): error: expected an expression
                   const char *, va_list *)
                                          ^

../.././libcpp/charset.c(1749): error: expected a ";"
      ATTRIBUTE_FPTR_PRINTF(5,0);
      ^

compilation aborted for ../.././libcpp/charset.c (code 2)

make[3]: *** [charset.o] Error 2

make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/zhuobuer/gcc-8.1.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libcpp'

make[2]: *** [all-stage1-libcpp] Error 2

make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

config.status: creating Makefile

config.status: creating config.h

config.status: config.h is unchanged

config.status: executing depdir commands

make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/zhuobuer/gcc-8.1.0'

make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/zhuobuer/gcc-8.1.0'

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have searched around but haven't got the answer to this one. Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error when I was compiling with Intel compilers, but not with GNU compilers.

Try compiling with (a previous version of) GNU compilers. That might solve your problem.